# Replace colors in an image without having to iterate through all pixels

Tags: java, android, image, iteration, processing

Let's say that I have an image like this one (in reality, I have a lot of them, but let's keep it simple)
[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tDQV.png) and I'd like to replace background color (that's the one that's not roads) with green color.

To do that I'd have to iterate through all of the pixels in the map and replace ones that match the color I want to remove.

But as you might think, my image is not a simple as 256x256 picture, but it's slightly bigger, it's 1440p, and the performance drop is significant.

How would I replace all of the unwanted pixels without iterating through all of the pixels.

I'm working with Processing 3 - Java(Android) and I'm currently using this piece of code:

```
for (x = 0; x < img.width; x++){
    for (int y = 0; y < img.height; y++) {
         //Color to transparent
         int index = x + img.width * y;
         if (img.pixels[index] == -1382175 || img.pixels[index] == 14605278 || img.pixels[index] == 16250871) {
            img.pixels[index] = color(0, 0, 0, 0);
         } else {
            img.pixels[index] = color(map(bright, 0, 255, 64, 192));
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with this one:

```
private PImage swapPixelColor(PImage img, int old, int now) {
    old &= ~0x00000000;
    now &= ~0x00000000;

    img.loadPixels();
    int p[] = img.pixels, i = p.length;

    while (i-- != 0) if ((p[i]) == old) p[i] = now;

    img.updatePixels();
    return img;
}
```

It works like a charm and it takes almost no time:

```
Swapped colors in 140ms // That's replacing it three times(different colors ofc)
```

Comment: Isn't this still iterating over every pixel? The only real difference is that you're caching the values instead of recreating them every iteration of the loop, right?

Comment: You are correct, but it's fast enough that it's useful.